# Android - unable to hide textView for a certain amount of time using a CountDownTimer

Tags: android, timer, textview, countdowntimer

I want to hide a textView on a click. A click triggers a timer for a certain time, after that time is up, the textView should be visible again. I try to hide the textView on a click, and make it visible again inside  `public void onFinish()`. For some reason, the textView is always visible. I tried using`view.setVisability(View.INVISIBLE)` and `view.setVisability(View.GONE)` but still no go.

EDIT
All other code inside the listener executes as needed, except for the visibility thing. Do i still need to define the textView as `clickable` inside the xml file?

EDIT 2
Im using `new CountDownTimer(25000, 1000)` on purpose, as the countdown timer is shown inside another element, so im not only trying to delay the execution.

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Log.i("textView: ","clicked");
        if (....){
            new CountDownTimer(25000, 1000) {
            {
             //some code...
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                otherTextView2.setText("done");
                textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
          }.start();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT 3
I managed to hide the textView, but this is a temporary workaround. on a click i set the following properties:

```
textView.setText("");
textView.setEnabled(false);
```

And once the time is up, I re-enable the textView and set the text again. I still would like to know how to solve this issue with proper code.

Comment: are you sure you are trying to hide the correct one? `textEditGo`, vs `textEdit`,

Comment: Yes. There was a typo. I've updated the code.

Comment: What i guess is that `setVisibility()`doesnt applies as you expect. After setting the visibility type, you need to redraw the view. I think just setting the property wont change it.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:clickable="true"` to the XML for the textview.

A good way to determine the issue is to put log statements inside the onClick handler to see if the event actually fired.

Answer (score 0):

try following:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        v.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
    },5000);            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be better to use `Handler().postDelayed` to achieve your goals,

```
    mTextEditGo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
    mTextEditGo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mTextEditGo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mTextEditGo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }, 2000);   // run after 2000ms
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You get a referrnce to the view being clicked on the onClick listener, try and use the "v" in the onclick method instaed of the "textview" you are currently using.

i.e -

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Log.i("textView: ","clicked");
        if (....){
            new CountDownTimer(25000, 1000) {
            {
             //some code...
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                otherTextView2.setText("done");
                v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                v.invalidate();
            }
          }.start();
        }
    }
}
```